# How do I calculate average from June 1 to June 30 annually and make it a dynamic function using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables in PowerBI, one modified date and one fact for customer scores. The relationship will be using the "Month Num" column. Score assessments take place every June, so I would like to be able to have the scores for 12 months (June 1 to June 30) averaged. Then I will just have a card comparing the Previous year score and Current year score. Is there a way to do this dynamically, so I do not have to change the year in the function every new year? I know using the AVERAGE function will be nested into the function somehow, but I am getting confused not using a calendar year and not seasoned enough to use Time Intelligence functions yet.

**Customer Score Table**

| Month | Month Num | Year | Score | Customer # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| June | 6 | 2020 | 94.9 | 11111 |
| July | 7 | 2020 | 97 | 11111 |
| months | continue | 2020 | 100 |  |
| June | 6 | 2021 | 89 | 22222 |
| July | 7 | 2021 | 91 | 22222 |
| months | continue | 2021 | 100 |  |
| June | 6 | 2022 | 93 | 33333 |
| July | 7 | 2022 | 94 | 33333 |

**Date Table**

| Month | Month Num | Month Initial |
| --- | --- | --- |
| january | 1 | J |
| feb | 2 | F |
| march | 3 | M |
| other | months | continued |

Comment: Add some dummy data. Without sample data on which you work, it's hard to answer and propose a solution.

Comment: @msta42a let me know if that helps any.